# How do I connect to SFTP with provided SSH Key?

Tags: ssh, sftp, ssh-keys, cyberduck

I was redirected to this StackExchange, it is my first time here. The extent of experience I have with SSH keys begins and ends with the one time I setup the ability to push code to GitHub.

I need to access a FTP server via Cyberduck. I am in SFTP and need to "Choose..." a SSH Private Key. I have the TEXT for the private key that was messaged to me. So I can copy and paste it into a file? I'm not sure how to proceed and every resource I find is to generate a key rather than save a file to upload.

Guidance and resources are appreciated.

Comment: The private key was sent to you? That's not a great start... (ideally you'd generate the keypair on your computer, and share the public key only)

Comment: You should be able to paste the text into a file, and select that file. It should begin with something like `-----BEGIN xx PRIVATE KEY-----` on a line, and end with a similar marker. The text between should be [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table)

Comment: Yes, the key was sent to me. Do I save this text in a file with a specific file . extension? Like .txt or something along those lines?

Comment: The extension shouldn't matter, `*.txt` is fine.

Comment: For Filezilla users: Choose "SFTP", enter the IP at "Host:", choose "Logon Type: Key file", insert correct username at "User:", choose private key file (note: rename it to yourfile`.ppk`). Then Filezilla can connect to the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can save the text that was sent to you as a file and use the built in "Choose..." feature on Cyberduck. I am on a Windows machine so I used the Notepad app. I assume TextEdit on a Mac would have similar results. Here are the steps:

1. Open Notepad
2. Paste the text that was provided for your SSH key
3. Save the file (I named mine `key.txt`)
4. Open Cyberduck
5. Select **Open Connection**
6. Select **SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol)** for the connection type
7. Enter server, port (22), username
8. You can skip password - it will use the SSH key
9. For SSH Private Key, select Choose... and find the save location of your file
10. Click **Connect**
11. The Unknown Fingerprint prompt will appear, click **Allow** (and you can select Always if this is a connection you trust and will often use)
12. You should see your files and/or your assigned folder location!

Answer (score 17):

if you use an sftp to connect to an sftp server, you should generate an ssh keypair (ie on unix: ssh-keygen) and provide your the *public* key (ie `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or `.ssh/id_ed25519.pub`) to the sftp-server-admin.

if your ssh private key is in the default directory, the software may find it automatically.

if you use openssh (sftp is a part of it), you can use

```
sftp -i <privateKey> user@example.com
```

to connect to the sftp server, once the sftp-server-admin has put your ssh *public* key to the right location (depends on the setup and the ssh server used).

Comment: Actually fails on RHEL6

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the nikiwaibel's answer, some sftp versions won't accept the "-i" so you can use the alternative

```
sftp -oIdentityFile=<privateKey.file> user@example.com
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: This should be a comment upvote